# Fixed Table Height in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I'm not sure if this is possible as I rarely work with tables, but I'm looking for a way to have a fixed height on my table and have everything else scroll over.

Demo works in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE: http://jsfiddle.net/wesbos/nxqQH/1/

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to embed the table in a div which has a overflow:scroll style attribute.

Comment: Thats what I've been thinking, I'd love to do it without changing my markup, but looks like I might have to

Comment: Also, I had to give a fixed height to that div.  But thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can also add the scroll to `tbody` instead of `table`. (if you can't use `div` as mentioned by MCB)

Comment: @Matthew Lock This is not working on IE7 but it's working on I8+ and Firefox! If you do `tbody{overflow-y:scroll; display:block; float:left; height:200px; width:318px;}`