# Display block is not working in IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I am using Bootstrap Table responsive in my rails 4 application.

I have a table structure like below:

```
<DIV class=table-responsive>
        <TABLE style="display: block" id=data class="table table-striped table-hover" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
            <THEAD>
            <TR>
            <TH> 1 </TH>
            <TH> 2 </TH>
            <TH> 3 </TH>
            <TH> 4 </TH>
            <TH> 5 </TH>  
            <TH> 6 </TH>    
            <TH> 7 </TH>    
            <TH> 8 </TH>    
            <TH> 9 </TH>    
            <TH> 10 </TH>
            </TR>
            </THEAD>
            <TBODY>
                <TR class=row0>
                    <TD>a</TD>
                    <TD>b</TD>
                    <TD>c</TD>
                    <TD>d</TD>
                    <TD>e</TD>
                    <TD>f</TD>
                    <TD>g</TD>
                    <TD>h</TD>
                    <TD>i </TD>
                    <TD>j</TD>
                </TR>
                <TR class=row0>
                    <TD>a</TD>
                    <TD>b</TD>
                    <TD>c</TD>
                    <TD>d</TD>
                    <TD>e</TD>
                    <TD>f</TD>
                    <TD>g</TD>
                    <TD>h</TD>
                    <TD>i </TD>
                    <TD>j</TD>
                </TR>
                <TR class=row0>
                    <TD>a</TD>
                    <TD>b</TD>
                    <TD>c</TD>
                    <TD>d</TD>
                    <TD>e</TD>
                    <TD>f</TD>
                    <TD>g</TD>
                    <TD>h</TD>
                    <TD>i </TD>
                    <TD>j</TD>
                </TR>
                ...
            </TBODY>

        </TABLE>
    </DIV>
```

I have added display block to the above table when its header count reaches more then 5, It works in Chrome and it creates a nice Scroll at the right end in Chrome.

When I run the same page in IE, display block is getting added to the table, but there is no change in the View, No scroll at the right end nor the height reduces.
     Kindly advise on this.

Comment: A demo in jsfiddle.net will go a long way, just saying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819545/ie9-tables-and-display-block)

Comment: As Max Seifert said, check out whether you have added `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start of HTML. What is the IE version you are using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044874/fixed-table-height-in-ie Solves my problem